# Class instantiate 2 times on MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a question. I'm working in a UWP application and i don't know how to use another class (external class _ViewModel) on my mainpage.xaml.cs. The class _vienmodel is already instantiate at the beginning of code (from App.xaml.cs class).

On the way that i do, i come 3 times on the constructor of my _viewmodel class :S

So when i come to the class MainPage.xmal.cs the value on my variable bras.Com.IsConnectionOk is false. But at the reality my variable is on true state.

Class MainPage:

```
namespace IHM_UWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Une page vide peut être utilisée seule ou constituer une page de destination au sein d'un frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public bool open = false;
        public bool close = false;
        /*public bool upAct = false;
        public bool downAct = false;
        public bool leftAct = false;
        public bool rightAct = false;*/

        private _ViewModel view = new _ViewModel(); // cette classe n'est pas bien implementé 
        private Brush colorButton = new SolidColorBrush();

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            colorButton = Up.Background;

        }

        private void KeyDown_detect(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // si la connexion est établie alors on peut envoyer les trames pour les touches de direction
            if (view.Bras.Com.IsConnectionOk == true)
            {
                if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Up)
                {
                    // Effet visuel pour indiquer que l'on a cliqué sur la touche UP 
                    Up.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
                    Down.Background = colorButton;
                    Left.Background = colorButton;
                    Right.Background = colorButton;
                    view.Bras.MoveArmUp();
                }
                if(e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Down)
                {
                    // Effet visuel pour indiquer que l'on a cliqué sur la touche DOWN
                    Down.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
                    Up.Background = colorButton;
                    Left.Background = colorButton;
                    Right.Background = colorButton;
                    view.Bras.MoveArmDown();
                }
                if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Right)
                {
                    // Effet visuel pour indiquer que l'on a cliqué sur la touche DOWN
                    Right.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
                    Up.Background = colorButton;
                    Left.Background = colorButton;
                    Down.Background = colorButton;
                    view.Bras.MoveArmRight();
                }
                if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Left)
                {
                    // Effet visuel pour indiquer que l'on a cliqué sur la touche DOWN
                    Left.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
                    Up.Background = colorButton;
                    Down.Background = colorButton;
                    Right.Background = colorButton;
                    view.Bras.MoveArmLeft();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Classe _ViewModel.cs:

```
namespace IHM_UWP
{
    public class _ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private GestionBras bras= new GestionBras(); //On peut ajouter cet instance dans la classe App.Xaml.cs?

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string str = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(str));
            }
        }

        public _ViewModel()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Commande pour lancer la connexion au bras
        /// </summary>
        private ICommand connect;


        public ICommand Connect
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.connect == null)
                    this.connect = new RelayCommand(() => this.Bras.ConnectAsync());
                return this.connect;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Commande pour ouvrir la pince
        /// </summary>
        private ICommand ouvrirPince;


        public ICommand OuvrirPince
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.ouvrirPince == null)
                    this.ouvrirPince = new RelayCommand(() => this.Bras.OuvrirPince());
                return this.ouvrirPince;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Commande pour fermer la pince
        /// </summary>
        private ICommand fermerPince;


        public ICommand FermerPince
        {
            get
            {
                if (this.fermerPince == null)
                    this.fermerPince = new RelayCommand(() => this.Bras.FermerPince());
                return this.fermerPince;
            }
        }

        // Class intermedaire pour la gestion de binding 
        public GestionBras Bras { get => bras; set => bras = value; }


    }
}
```

Class EnvCoord.xaml.cs:

```
namespace IHM_UWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Une page vide peut être utilisée seule ou constituer une page de destination au sein d'un frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class EnvCoord : Page
    {
        string xcoord = string.Empty;
        string ycoord = string.Empty;
        string zcoord = string.Empty;

        private _ViewModel view = new _ViewModel();

        public EnvCoord()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CloseWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }

        private void EnvoyerCoord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            xcoord = CoordX.Text;
            ycoord = CoordY.Text;
            zcoord = CoordZ.Text;

            view.Bras.SendCoorGeom(xcoord, ycoord, zcoord);

            Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

        }

    }
}
```

Class App.xaml.cs:

```
namespace IHM_UWP
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Fournit un comportement spécifique à l'application afin de compléter la classe Application par défaut.
    /// </summary>
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public IHM_UWP._ViewModel view = new IHM_UWP._ViewModel();

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialise l'objet d'application de singleton.  Il s'agit de la première ligne du code créé
        /// à être exécutée. Elle correspond donc à l'équivalent logique de main() ou WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoqué lorsque l'application est lancée normalement par l'utilisateur final.  D'autres points d'entrée
        /// seront utilisés par exemple au moment du lancement de l'application pour l'ouverture d'un fichier spécifique.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Détails concernant la requête et le processus de lancement.</param>
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

            // Ne répétez pas l'initialisation de l'application lorsque la fenêtre comporte déjà du contenu,
            // assurez-vous juste que la fenêtre est active
            if (rootFrame == null)
            {
                // Créez un Frame utilisable comme contexte de navigation et naviguez jusqu'à la première page
                rootFrame = new Frame();

                rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                {
                    //TODO: chargez l'état de l'application précédemment suspendue
                }

                // Placez le frame dans la fenêtre active
                Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
            }

            if (e.PrelaunchActivated == false)
            {
                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // Quand la pile de navigation n'est pas restaurée, accédez à la première page,
                    // puis configurez la nouvelle page en transmettant les informations requises en tant que
                    // paramètre
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), e.Arguments);
                }
                // Vérifiez que la fenêtre actuelle est active
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appelé lorsque la navigation vers une page donnée échoue
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Frame à l'origine de l'échec de navigation.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Détails relatifs à l'échec de navigation</param>
        void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appelé lorsque l'exécution de l'application est suspendue.  L'état de l'application est enregistré
        /// sans savoir si l'application pourra se fermer ou reprendre sans endommager
        /// le contenu de la mémoire.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">Source de la requête de suspension.</param>
        /// <param name="e">Détails de la requête de suspension.</param>
        private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Remettre tous les moteurs à leur position initial
            for (int i = 0; i < view.Bras.Moteur.Length; i++)
            {
                view.Bras.InitialPosition(view.Bras.Moteur[i].Num_pin);
            }

            var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
            //TODO: enregistrez l'état de l'application et arrêtez toute activité en arrière-plan

            deferral.Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

How i can do to recover the _ViewModel class (with all the updated variables values) from my App.xaml.cs? I need to use _viewmodel on the Envcoord.xaml.cs and on my mainpage.xaml.cs

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: So you clearly instantiate _ViewModel class 3 times - in App.xaml.cs, in Envcoord.xaml.cs and in Mainpage.xaml.cs. To reuse same instance of your viewmodel, you have either to provide it through Dependency Injection or make it a static property in some class and just call to it from those pages.

Comment: Thanks but can you give me an example?

Comment: Make `view` property in App.xaml.cs as `public static IHM_UWP._ViewModel view = new IHM_UWP._ViewModel()`. And then remove `view` property from Envcoord.xaml.cs and Mainpage.xaml.cs and use that static property from your App class directly where you need it - i.e. `App.view.Bras.SendCoorGeom(xcoord, ycoord, zcoord)`.

Comment: But note, that using static properties usually indicates poor application design. Its way better to introduce some DI framework into your project and manage shared resources using services with different lifetime scopes. But unfortunately, can't help you with example how to do i this way, because it is not a 5 minute work to do.

Comment: Thank you i apply as you tell me to do, but this is not working because `this.InitializeComponent();` on the MainPage.xaml.cs calls once the _ViewModel Class. my value of `App.view.Bras.Com.IsConnectionOk` is still to false even if it change

Comment: Maybe that is sync issues, so connection is opened after `InitializeComponent()` is called? Because it looks like connection is opened in `async` manner.

Comment: Yes connection is open when i click on a button so it is not launched before Initializecomponent

Comment: So is `App.view.Bras.Com.IsConnectionOk` working correctly inside `KeyDown_detect` handler in MainPage.cs ?

Comment: no is not working. I launch my application and _viewmodel is call two times. when i launch the connection my variable IsConnectionOk change to true, but when i verified this value on my class MainPage.xaml.cs `App.view.Bras.Com.IsConnectionOk` it is false :/

Comment: If `_viewmodel` constructor is called twice, than you still have some multiple instances instead of using static property from `App` class. Search for `_viewmodel` constructor usages and make sure it is only instantiated once in `App` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a new instance in `MainPage` and `EnvCoord`, you should use the instance that you have already created in `App.xaml.cs`. You can access it using the `App.Current` property:

```
public sealed partial class EnvCoord : Page
{
    string xcoord = string.Empty;
    string ycoord = string.Empty;
    string zcoord = string.Empty;

    private readonly _ViewModel view;

    public EnvCoord()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        view = (App.Current as App).view;
        DataContext = view;
    }

    private void CloseWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }

    private void EnvoyerCoord_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xcoord = CoordX.Text;
        ycoord = CoordY.Text;
        zcoord = CoordZ.Text;

        view.Bras.SendCoorGeom(xcoord, ycoord, zcoord);

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but is the same solution proposed by Yura but this is not working, i think my program instantiate twice my _ViewModel constructor but i don't know why. when i execute in my MainPage.xaml.cs `this.InitializeComponent();` it calls the _Viewmodel class but i don't know why

Comment: @AnnyVivas: Of course it's working. If an instance of your view model is created on `InitializeComponent()` you probably create another instance of the view model in your XAML markup: `<local:_ViewModel />`. You should not do this.

Comment: ohhhhh yes i have this on my MainPage.xaml :/. so i should delete this part of code of my MainPage.xaml? `<Page.DataContext>
        <local:_ViewModel/>
    </Page.DataContext>`      On this line: `view = (App.Current as App).view;` (MainPage.xaml.cs) "view" after point, is initialized on the app.xaml.cs class as? how? in propfull mode? or `public static IHM_UWP._ViewModel view = new IHM_UWP._ViewModel()`

Comment: Yes, and set the `DataContext` of the view in the constructor as per my edited answer: `DataContext = view;`